# RingCentral JS SDK - Refresh token is missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, ringcentral

I am using the RingCentral JS SDK (v. 3.1.1). I use the API from my server only so I am using a password workflow with the function `rcsdk.platform().login()` (from the [doc here](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-js#password-flow)).

I am using the API only to send SMS for now.

Everything was working fine until yesterday. Then when I had to send an SMS, I got the error `Refresh Token is missing`.

I am aware of [the refresh function in the SDK](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-js/blob/master/src/platform/Platform.js#L375). The line 392 seems to be the one throwing my error. What I don't know is why, since I am using correct username, password and so on.

Sending SMS is a vital part of my user workflow, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation said "The SDK takes care of the token lifecycle. It will refresh tokens for you automatically. ..."

Do you handle the refresh token manually? Did you check if it has a valid token by calling this:

```
rcsdk.platform().auth().accessTokenValid(); // returns boolean
```

You can also implement the following code and print some log to see if the refresh token failed some how.

```
platform.on(platform.events.refreshError, function(e){
    // do something, usually open a login page
});
```

Comment: In case anyone else is interested, I found "the documentation" here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ringcentral/sdk, even though that's not exactly the package I'm using, it was the documentation I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and while I'm not sure we were making the same mistake the root cause was that the Auth was not being set properly.  I was using `rcsdk.platform().auth().setData(authData)` to set the data but unfortunately I was not formatting authData properly as JSON first.